# How to add a human-readable date format for start_epoch in the /_cat/snapshots in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, date-formatting

How to add a human-readable date format for `start_epoch` and `end_epoch` in the `/_cat/snapshots` [API in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/cat-snapshots.html)?

Similarly, other APIs seem to lack the support for date formatting:

- `start_time` in the `_cat/tasks` [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/cat-tasks.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have a very good point given the intent of the `_cat` endpoint is to be human readable, and epoch isn't really human friendly. unfortunately there is no way to do this

you would be best off creating a feature request to have this added as a flag :)

Comment: Posted in their Slack channel too. Thanks for taking the time!